# How to add number in each new line in a multiline textbox C# / ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multiline textbox in c#/asp.net, which I  want to add the number of each line when the user press Enter....

I tried to do that but it didn't work.

Comment: Always make sure to show what you have tried to help us guide you and know that you have tried something out from yourself as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not a foolproof solution - the following will add the line number.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" onKeyup="onTextBox1Change(this)"></asp:TextBox>

function onTextBox1Change(ele) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                var lnNumber = (ele.value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;

                ele.value = ele.value + (lnNumber+1);
            }
        }
```

You will still need to handle the edit (for example what happens if the user goes back to first line and then presses enter from somewhere in between)

Answer (score 2):

add a `inputchanged` event on the textbox, and whenever the input changes, see if the enter was pressed or not. If yes, then get the current text of textbox and append `/n` to it

Answer (score 1):

Add onkeypress event to the textBox like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in the EnterEvent method like this

```
function EnterEvent(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // get the textbox text and append /n to it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you provide your code here. KeyDown event would help you in this case.

Codebehind:

```
private void txtBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Insert the code you want to run when the text changes here!
    if(e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {  
       //try from the below
       //txtShowCount = ViewState["count"] + 1;
       txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + "\r\n";
       txtBox1.Text = txtBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

The above may help you if its not data binding

Comment: Modify the above according to your code. Coz it showing the count of enter key pressed in txtShowcount textbox and it would also add the newline with the text in txtbox1.Text