# How to append line numbers to the beginning of every line in a multi-line textbox every time the "ENTER" key is pressed?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, line-numbers

i went through these , but they didn't help me in my situation

this doesn't work in my case because it it contains KeyData or KeyCode methods in answers which shows error when i try to run.
[How to add number in each new line in a multiline textbox C# / ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164367/how-to-add-number-in-each-new-line-in-a-multiline-textbox-c-sharp-asp-net)

i tried this one which doesn't work in my case because it used when a button is pressed
[Adding new line of data to TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318561/adding-new-line-of-data-to-textbox/13319102)

this one just adds a a few strings like first, second , third and that is , which doesn't help in my case.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/320713/Adding-new-line-in-textbox-without-repalcing-exist

I went through 20 search results in Google , many of them were not relevant while others weren't helpful in my situation.

Comment: Did you see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567404/wpf-richtextbox-to-create-editor-with-line-numbers

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your _closest_ attempt.

Comment: you wont get the exact code anywhere..using the examples try what you wnt to achieve and share if something is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the answer by computhoms it didn't work exactly how i wanted to.

First the KeyDown event didn't generated any results , it seems the when pressing the Enter key the KeyDown event doesn't fire and doesn't generate any results. 
so instead i used PreviewKeyDown event which works.

Second it didn't Write the line number for the first line. Also for subsequent numbers it creates the number in a new line then move the cursor to another line so the effect would be like this:

some text

2

some text

3

some text

and so on.

the result i want is i want it to be like this :

1-some text.

2-some text.

3-some text.

so i modified the code given by Computhos which gave me the right results.
here is the code i used:

After Creating a TextBox in xaml and creating the PreviewKeyDown event like this

```
  <TextBox  PreviewKeyDown="LifeGoalsTextBox_PreviewKeyDown" x:Name="LifeGoalsTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

I went to the code behind and wrote this code:

```
private void LifeGoalsTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                string txt = LifeGoalsTextBox.Text;
                int lineNumber = txt.Split('\n').Length ;
                string lineNumberString = lineNumber.ToString();

                if (lineNumber == 0)
                {
                    LifeGoalsTextBox.Text = LifeGoalsTextBox.Text.Insert(0, "1") + '-';
                }
                else
                {
                    lineNumber++;
                    int lastLine = 1 + LifeGoalsTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf('\n');
                    LifeGoalsTextBox.Text = LifeGoalsTextBox.Text.Insert(lastLine, lineNumberString+ '-') ;

                    LifeGoalsTextBox.CaretIndex = LifeGoalsTextBox.Text.Length;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the question, you want to add the line number of each new line inside the textbox. In order to do just this, you would need to add a `TextBox` in your view with the `KeyDown` event

```
<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" x:Name="txtBox" />
```

Then, in the code-behind of the view, you can check for the key to be the "enter" key and add the line number to the text

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        string txt = txtBox.Text;
        int lineNumber = txt.Split('\n').Length + 1;
        txtBox.Text += '\n' + lineNumber.ToString();
        txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- The line `txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;` places the caret at the end of the text after editing it. Otherwise when you press enter, the caret is reset to the beginning of the text.
- You would need to append the first line number when the textbox is empty.
- You would probably need to handle the editing, i.e. so that the user cannot remove the line numbers for example.

**Edit**

If using the `AcceptsReturn` property of the `TextBox`, the event `KeyDown` is directly handled by the TextBox and note bubbled up to the parents. In this case, you have to use the `PreviewKeyDown` event, see [MSDN Routing Strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview#routing_strategies)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. for some reason the KeyDown event for the Enter key doesn't work . I tried the KeyUp but it gives me the wrong result. it will create an empty line and then a line number. For example when i first press enter with no text in the TextBox it gives 3 then on the next Enter it creates a space then a number 5 and so on.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the explanation of the behavior you encountered. This is why you had extra lines when using other events with the `AcceptsReturn=true`, because I explicitely handled the new line in the `KeyDown` event as it wasn't handled by the TextBox.